# Login to website using Google Apps script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Login in to a website using Google Apps Script has been discussed here previously and I most probably have seen them all and tried them all. But nothing seems to work. I must oversee something and would appreciate your help.

I am trying to login to this website https://teslaclub.ch/clubdesk/www?action=login&

As it looks like the relevant login information is the following:

```html
<form method="post" action="www" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
<input type="hidden" name="redirectUrl" value="HxgrZFvkpAK4n-IGMS4gSQ">
<table class="admin">
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Benutzername:</td>
            <td class="field"><input id="userId" name="userId" type="text" value="my login name comes here"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Passwort:</td>
            <td class="field"><input id="password" name="password" type="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="error" colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="comment" colspan="2" style="line-height: 28px;color:#2eab66;">
                <a href="www?action=signupUser&">
                    Zugang anfordern</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="www?action=recover&">
                    Passwort vergessen</a>/<a href="www?action=changePassword&">
                ändern</a>
                <input style="float: right;" type="submit" value="Anmelden">
            </td>
    </table>
</form>
```

I am trying to login like this (which i took from other examples and modified it):

```js
function loginToSite(){
  var url = "https://teslaclub.ch/clubdesk/www?action=login&"; //change this.
  var payload = {
    "userId":"my login name comes here", //change this.
    "password":"my password comes here" //and change this. done. no need to enter anything elsewhere.
  }; 
  var opt = {
    "payload":payload,
    "method":"post"
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, opt);
  if ( response.getResponseCode() == 200 ) { //could not log in.
    var result = "Couldn't login. Please make sure your username/password is correct.";
  } 
  else if ( response.getResponseCode() == 303 ) { //login was successful. you might receive 302 response code as well depending upon the site. So try changing it to 302.
     var result = "Logged in successfully";
     var cookie = response.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];     
     var header = {
       'Cookie':cookie[1] //taking the second cookie because when redirected, a new cookie is set. If the page does not redirect, you might need to use cookie[0] here. Try it out yourself!
     };
  }
Logger.log(result);
}
```

I always get a 200 response back. Therefore I think I am missing a function to "press" the login (Anmelden) button. But I am not sure how I could do that.

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Heinz

Comment: Thanks. 
Unfortunately I am not experienced in HTML programming. But I did quite a lot in Google Apps Script.
So, what I tried in the payload is this, but I am not at all sure, if that is correct:
  var payload = {
    "userId":"my login name comes here", //change this.
    "password":"my password comes here", //and change this. done. no need to enter anything elsewhere.
    "action":"login",
    "redirectUrl": "HxgrZFvkpAK4n-IGMS4gSQ"
  }; 
Unfortunately it does still not work (still getting 200 error). Any other thoughts?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortuanately I still cannot make it to work. Any body else who can help me?